# how to pass TypeScript Interface Object array as props in React Child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I am learning react and Typescript,
I need to pass TypeScript Interface Object from the parent to the child component, if I remove TypeScript and do it in pure React, it works.

TypeScript Interface

```
export interface IUser {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  username: string;
  email: string;
}
```

Parent.tsx

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { IUser } from "./ApiInterface";
import Child from "./Child";
export default function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState<IUser[]>();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => setUsers(res as IUser[]));
  }, []);

  return <Child users={users} />;
}
```

Child.tsx

```
import { IUser } from "./ApiInterface";

const Child: React.FunctionComponent<IUser[]> = (users: IUser[]): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <div>
      {users.map((u, i) => (
        <h1 key={u.id}>{u.name}</h1>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
export default Child;
```

error

```
ERROR in src/App.tsx:14:17
TS2322: Type '{ users: IUser[] | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IUser[]'.
  Property 'users' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IUser[]'.
    12 |   }, []);
    13 |
  > 14 |   return <Child users={users} />;
       |                 ^^^^^
    15 | }
    16 |
```

Comment: Try this `const [users, setUsers] = useState<IUser[]>([]);`. Basically initialise with some default value

Comment: tried, but still getting the same error 

  const [users, setUsers] = useState<IUser[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => setUsers(res as IUser[]));
  }, []);

  return <Child users={users} />;


TS2322: Type '{ users: IUser[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IUser[]'.
  Property 'users' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IUser[]'.
    12 |   }, []);
    13 |
  > 14 |   return <Child users={users} />;
       |                 ^^^^^
    15 | }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong type for your child component. You are using `React.FC<IUser[]>` which means that your child component expects an array of `IUser` objects as its props, but you are passing an object with a `users` property that contains an array of `IUser` objects.

To fix this, you need to use the correct type for your child component and set an initial value for your `users` state variable

For example:

```
// define correct type for child component
interface ChildProps {
  users: IUser[];
}

const Child: React.FC<ChildProps> = ({ users }: ChildProps): JSX.Element => {
  return (...);
};


// initialize state value
const [users, setUsers] = useState<IUser[]>([]);
```

You can see the whole example here: [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-dubinsky-x6d2wz?file=/src/App.tsx)

---

### UPDATED ANSWER

You don't necessarily have to create a new interface for every interface you want to pass as a prop. You can also write the type of your prop inline, like @sai vineeth suggested in the comment, or just use the existing interface directly.

For example:

```
const Child: React.FC<{ users: IUser[] }> = ({ users }: { users: IUser[] }): JSX.Element => { return (...); };
```

But creating interface is better. Creating a separate interface for your props can improve your code quality, reusability and consistency.

Ultimately, you have to decide what works best for you and your situation, but I think it's a good idea to create a separate interface for your props whenever possible.

Comment: thankyou for the solution, it's working, just 1 question, so in TypeScript for each interface I want to pass as prop eg IUser in this case, do I have to create another Interface ie ChildProps, which will hold the type of IUser interface? Isn't this redundancy?

Comment: you can also do
 const Child: React.FC = ({ users }: {users: IUser[]}): JSX.Element => {
  return (...);
};
but creating interface is better.
React component will accept multiple props so, creating interface will be better, as this can be reused, and we can add additional props, and it will affect components where interface is used