# how to pass single TypeScript Interface Object as props in React Child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

Hi i am new to typescript and react, i need to pass a single TypeScript object as props in Child component, i found a similar question

> [how to pass TypeScript Interface Object array as props in React Child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76718307/how-to-pass-typescript-interface-object-array-as-props-in-react-child-component)
> but here its trying to send a array of type script object, but I need to send a single object, i tried changing all array to single objects but its not working.

interface

```
export type IUserType = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  username: string;
  email: string;
};
```

Parent.tsx

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { IUserType } from "./ApiInterface";
import "./App.css";
import Child from "./Child";
export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<IUserType>();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => setUser(res as IUserType));
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <Child user={user} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Child.tsx

```
import { IUserType } from "./ApiInterface";

const Child: React.FunctionComponent<IUserType> = (user): JSX.Element => {
  return <div>{JSON.stringify(user)}</div>;
};
export default Child;
```

error

```
ERROR in src/App.tsx:23:14
TS2322: Type '{ user: IUserType | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IUserType'.
  Property 'user' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IUserType'.
    21 |         }}
    22 |       />
  > 23 |       <Child user={user} />
       |              ^^^^
    24 |     </>
    25 |   );
    26 | }
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks @Diwakaran and @erkanom
so here is the final working code, might help some one facing same issue

interface

```
export type IUserType = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  username: string;
  email: string;
};
export interface IChildProps {
  user: IUserType;
}
```

parent.tsx

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { IUserType } from "./ApiInterface";
import "./App.css";
import Child from "./Child";
export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<IUserType>();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => setUser(res as IUserType));
  }, []);
  return <>{user && <Child user={user} />}</>; <-- here we are checking if user is present , then only call Child component
}
```

child.tsx

```
import { IChildProps } from "./ApiInterface";
const Child: React.FunctionComponent<IChildProps> = ({ user }): JSX.Element => {
  return <div>{JSON.stringify(user)}</div>;
};
export default Child;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Pls. check prop type for your child component. While defining typescript props for child component, it expects a JS object, with each prop described as mentioned in **`IChildProps`** below.

```
import { IUserType } from "./ApiInterface";
interface IChildProps {
  user: IUser;
}
const Child: React.FunctionComponent<IChildProps> = ({user}): JSX.Element => {
  return <div>{JSON.stringify(user)}</div>;
};
export default Child;
```

Comment: hi I updated the interface 
export type IUserType = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  username: string;
  email: string;
};
export interface IChildProps {
  user: IUserType;
}

child
import { IChildProps } from "./ApiInterface";
const Child: React.FunctionComponent<IChildProps> = ({ user }): JSX.Element => {
  return <div>{JSON.stringify(user)}</div>;
};
export default Child;

but still same error in parent at line

  <Child user={user} />

TS2322: Type 'IUserType | undefined' is not assignable to type 'IUserType'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'IUserType'

Comment: This is not the same error. I think this error is due to Parent component has possibility of having user being passed while user is undefined(before fetch is completed, user will not have any value).  Try  below update in Parent component
 <>
      user && <Child user={user} />
    </>

Comment: ok, this works
{user && <Child user={user} />}

but 1 question, in order to paas IUserType as prop, we have to create another interface IChildProps, isn't this redundancy?

Comment: `const Child: React.FunctionComponent<{user: IUser}>`

If you want to get rid of definition of interface, you can use inline the types in the component. 
Useful link for react typescript https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/

Answer (score 0):

In TypeScript, interfaces are used to define the structure and behavior of objects. They are a compile-time construct and exist only during the development and build process. Once the code is transpiled to JavaScript and executed at runtime, interfaces are not available.

When working with React components and props, it's important to understand that props are essentially a way to pass data from a parent component to a child component. Props are passed as runtime values and are not part of the build-time type checking. Therefore, you cannot directly pass an interface as a prop from a parent component to a child component.You can use generics though.

Comment: ok, so how should i paas it?
i created another type export interface IChildProps {
  user: IUserType;
}

updated child const Child: React.FunctionComponent<IChildProps> = ({ user }): JSX.Element => 

but still same error at    <Child user={user} />

Answer (score 0):

Change your child component to (If you want to pass full user object you need to change like below else you need to pass individual user properties )

```
interface ChildProps {
  user: IUserType;
}
const Child: React.FunctionComponent<ChildProps> = ({ user }): JSX.Element => {
  return <div>{JSON.stringify(user)}</div>;
};
```

and main to

```
export const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<IUserType>();
  console.log('xscdvfbg');
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => setUser(res as IUserType));
  }, []);
  return <>{user != null ? <Child user={user} /> : <div>loading ...</div>}</>;
};
```

Your component renders before processing request and at that time user will be null so we add a condition if user is null don't render child.
you can use loading property also.

Full code - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-starter-typescript-amemrn?file=App.tsx

Edit for Comment
If you have child this

```
const Child: React.FunctionComponent<IUserType> = (user): JSX.Element => {
  return <div>{JSON.stringify(user)}</div>;
};
```

That means you are expecting props

```
<Child id={0} name={''} username={''} email={''} />
```

Comment: in order to paas IUserType as prop, we have to create another interface ChildProps , isn't this redundancy?

Comment: you can also use const Child: React.FunctionComponent = ({ user }:{user:IUserType}): JSX.Element => {
  return <div>{JSON.stringify(user)}</div>;
};
but creating interface is better for reading and re-usability

Comment: @stacyanderson I edited answer, what is required if React.FunctionComponent<IUserType> is used instead of React.FunctionComponent<ChildProps> 
also its not reduntant in future if you want to pass extra props it will be easy

Answer (score 0):

type.tsx

```
export type IUserType = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  username: string;
  email: string;
};
```

Parent.tsx

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { IUserType } from "./ApiInterface";
import "./App.css";
import Child from "./Child";
export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<IUserType | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => setUser(res));
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      {user && <Child user={user} />}
    </>
  );
}
```

child.tsx

```
import { IUserType } from "./types";

type props = {
  user: IUserType;
};

const Child = ({ user }: props) => {
  return <div>{JSON.stringify(user)}</div>;
};
export default Child;
```